# Python R^2 calculations going awry

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I'm trying to do some basic analysis on data that I have in a csv. The data has a timestamp, against which there is a value for "Test A" and for "Test B". [[csv file data sample]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKMDU.jpg)

I've got averages for both Test A and Test B, and the difference between the test results. But I really need to calculate the r^2 value to see how the two tests correlate. I know a really easy way to do this in excel, but I have a lot of data so it needs to be coded for best. The section of code I have to calculate r^2 returns the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'LinregressResult' and 'int'

I wonder if it's perhaps because I am doing it on column data in float64 format?? [[TypeError message]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NprZh.jpg)

Ideally I'm also looking for a way to analyse only sections of the data - I want to analyse the data for each hour (45 data points per hour). Anyone have a way to only include a certain section of rows?

Many thanks!!

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

# Read the file in csv 
data_input = pd.read_csv("StackOF_r2.csv", low_memory=False)

#Output the number of rows
print("Total rows: {0}".format(len(data_input)))

# See which headers are available
print(list(data_input))

# Get the data from the data columns
data_A = data_input['Test A']
data_B = data_input['Test B']

# Average the data for Test A
Test_A = data_input['Test A'].mean()
print 'Test A Average: ', round(Test_A, 4)

# Average the data for Test B
Test_B = data_input['Test B'].mean()
print 'Test B Average: ', round(Test_B, 4)

# Calculate difference to between tests
Error = Test_A - Test_B
print 'Error (difference between averages): ', round(abs(Error), 4)

# Work out the r2 value between the two tests
r_value = stats.linregress(data_A, data_B)
print "r_value: ", r_value
print "R-squared: ", r_value**2

print data_input['Test A'].dtypes
```

Comment: The answer is spelled in whole letters in the error message: `r_value` is a `LinregressResult` (whatever this might be), so you can't use it as an int. Check scipy documentation for how to properly use this object or build an int from it.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html this should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced your snippet and it should now work for you. The problem you were having is that linregress returns multiple values, so you have to have a comma separated list on the left of the equals sign to capture them all, even if you don't use them.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

# Read the file in csv 
data_input = pd.read_csv("StackOF_r2.csv", low_memory=False)

#Output the number of rows
print("Total rows: {0}".format(len(data_input)))

# See which headers are available
print(list(data_input))

# Get the data from the data columns
data_A = data_input['Test A']
data_B = data_input['Test B']

# Average the data for Test A
Test_A = data_input['Test A'].mean()
print 'Test A Average: ', round(Test_A, 4)

# Average the data for Test B
Test_B = data_input['Test B'].mean()
print 'Test B Average: ', round(Test_B, 4)

# Calculate difference to between tests
Error = Test_A - Test_B
print 'Error (difference between averages): ', round(abs(Error), 4)

# Work out the r2 value between the two tests
##### This is the correction #####
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(data_A, data_B)
print "r_value: ", r_value
print "R-squared: ", r_value**2

print data_input['Test A'].dtypes
```

[Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)

Comment: Thanks so much Theo!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`r_value` is not a `int` or `float` instead is of type `LinregressResult`
to access the rvalue you would have to do one of this two

```
v = stats.linregress(x, y)
v.rvalue
```

or

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
```